# Sign in with Facebook, Twitter, Google developed in php

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, twitter

I'm searching a system to sign in with acebook, Twitter, Google developed in php.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this - http://openid.net/developers/libraries/